# How to use the search in acts as taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-taggable

I am using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem.

i want to use search both name as well as tags in single search field

my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_taggable
  attr_accessor: :name, :age, :country, tag_list

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class UserAppsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
    //@users = User.tagged_with(params[:search])
  end
end
```

Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add both results one to another using + :

```
@users = User.search(params[:search])
@users = @users + User.tagged_with(params[:search])
```

A better solution will be to change your search method in the model to return the full result:

```
where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") + tagged_with(search)
```

but if you want to split the name search from the tag search, you can split them into scopes or something like that and then use it:

```
scope :name_contains, -> (query) { where('name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%") }
```

and in your search method:

```
name_contains(search) + tagged_with(search)
```

btw if you want the name search to be case insensitive use something like:

```
scope :name_contains, -> (query) { where("REPLACE (lower(name), ' ', '' ) like ?", "%#{query.downcase}%") }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Now i am having pagination issue when we add two scope with "+"

Comment: scope :tagged_with, lambda { |tag|
    {
         :joins => "INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.taggable_id = user.id\
                 INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id AND taggings.taggable_type = 'User'",
         :conditions => ["tags.name = ?", tag]
   }
  }

Comment: i solved my pagination issue of tagged_with by adding `.order(:id)` to the result... so try `@users.order(:id)`

Comment: '+' makes the result an array which is useless.